# Confusion regarding Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Threads synchronization in java and I have the following code :

```
 class abs{
    int x=0;
    public void increment(){
        for(int i =0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
        //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());   
        x++;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    }
    
    
    
}

class thread_creation extends Thread{
    abs t;
    thread_creation(abs x){
        t=x;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        t.increment();
        
        
    }
    
}
public class Test_sync  {
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abs ob = new abs();
        thread_creation t1 = new thread_creation(ob);
        thread_creation t2 = new thread_creation(ob);
        t1.start();
        
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

When I run the code , I get the following output :

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
2
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

I have many questions regarding this output :

1. Why the output didn't start with 1 ? Initially x= 0 , so when the first thread increments and output x , then we should see 1 in the output ?
2. Why the output has value of 2  twice ?

I am very confused , so someone please explain why we got this output ?

Comment: 1. Because you incremented `x` before you printed it. 2. Because there is no synchronization or `volatile` in your code, so you have a race condition. Making `x` volatile will fix it.

Comment: Besides the actual question: please follow the basic java code conventions. It hurts my eyes to look at this. In particular: class names should start with a capital, and use CamelCase if there's multiple words in it, never underscores ('_').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the threads use a single variable to count.

```
A x+=1 (1)
B x+=1 (2)
A starts print (2), and goes to sleep
B prints 2
B keeps working, incrementing x, printing 3 to 11
B goes to sleep
A finishes the print of "2" it started a while back
```

Clarification of followup questions:

x is owned by the object `ob` of class `abs` there is only one which is shared across threads.

i is owned by the function `public void increment()` and there are two independent calls of it.

As to the behaviour of sleeping on printing... That's pretty much the whole point of threads. print takes forever from a cpu point of view and there are exclusive assets (there is only one console) involved

Comment: I have another question please , Why both threads don't share the loop counter variable i ? I see from the output every thread increment x 10 times and hence they don't share the loop counter , so I am wondering why they don't share it , although they share the variable x ? Moreover , why Thread A sleeps  when print (2) ? I think this is not random because when I run the code I always get this output ,and hence , Thread A always sleeps when printing 2 .

Comment: The loop counter is set to zero twice - once for each thread. It depends on thread switching as to what happens, and the result is somewhat indeterminate. From the output it looks like a context switch does not happen, so the same loop counter gets used twice in serial thread executions.

Comment: Thanks a lot But why  Threads A sleeps when printing 2 ?

Comment: Added a few clarifications

Comment: @gnight So for the reason A sleeps while printing is because the console is possessed by Thread B ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but responding to a comment:

> Why both threads don't share the loop counter variable `i`?...

That's because `i` is a *local variable* within the `increment()` method. Each call to `increment()` gets its own distinct `i`, which is created when the method is called, and which lives only until the method returns.

> ...although they share the variable x ?

Your `x` on the other hand is a *member variable* (a.k.a., a *field*) of the `abs` class. Each instance of the `abs` class gets its own distinct `x`, and that `x` lives as long as the instance lives. Your `main()` method creates just one instance of `abs`, and gives it to both threads.

What sets the two variables apart is where they are declared. `i` is declared inside the `increment()` method body. That's what makes it local. `x` is declared outside of any method, but inside the declaration of `class abs {...}`. That's what makes it an instance variable.*

---

* There are also `static` variables that can be declared inside a class, but I won't go in to that here.