# Trying to understand shared variables in java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code :

```
class thread_creation extends Thread{
    int t;
    thread_creation(int x){
        t=x;
    }
    
    public void run() {
    increment();
        
        
    }
    
    public void increment() {
        for(int i =0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
            t++;
    System.out.println(t);
        }
        
    }
}




public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i =0;
        thread_creation t1 = new thread_creation(i);
        thread_creation t2 = new thread_creation(i);
        t1.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

When I run it , I get  :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Why I am getting this output ? According to my understanding ,  the variable i is a shared variable between the two threads created. So according to the code , the first thread will execute and increments i 10 times , and hence , i will be equal to 10 . The second thread will start after the first one because of the sleep statement and since i is shared , then the second thread will start will i=10 and will start incrementing it 10 times to have i = 20 , but this is not the case in the output , so why that ?

Comment: `i` is not shared. You created two thread instances, hence two instances of `i`. Make `i` static, then it will be shared, and you will have a race.

Comment: There is no shared variable. You created two instances of a class that have their own instance variables. They dont have anything to do with each other.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have made i static and still I dont get a race condition .public class test {
   static int i = 0;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  thread_creation t1 = new thread_creation(i);
  thread_creation t2 = new thread_creation(i);
  t1.start();
  try {
   Thread.sleep(500);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  t2.start();
 }

}

Comment: @JhanzaibHumayun How do I pass a shared variable then ?

Comment: Because of the sleep, it is very unlikely that you'll observe a race. That doesn't mean it is not there.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have one more question please  , If i is an object of a certain class say A ( instead of int ) and t is declared as of type A . Then i will be shared object or will be local for each thread ?

Comment: @BurakSerdar For example in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639928/confusion-regarding-threads-in-java/71639998#71639998  is the member "x" of object "ob" is shared between the two threads ? Sorry but I am confused and I need to understand this concept. Thanks alot.

Comment: If you create one object `i` and assign that to two instances of threads, then it will be a shared variable. Not an int, or other primitive type though. Only Objects.

Comment: Your threads are not using `i`, they are using `t`. You need to make `t` shared, or make your threads use `test.i` instead of `t` to observe any behaviour associated with shared variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that `int t;` in `thread_creation` is a shared variable.  I'm afraid you are mistaken.  Each `t` instance is a different variable.  So the two threads are updating distinct counters.

The output you are seeing reflects that.

---

This is the nub of your question:

> How do I pass a shared variable then ?

Actually, you can't<sup>1</sup>.  Strictly a shared variable is actually a variable belonging to a shared object.  You cannot pass a variable *per se*.  Java does not allow passing of variables.  This is what *"Java does not support call-by-reference"* **really** means.  You can't pass or return a variable or the address of a variable in any method call.  (Or in any other way.)

In Java you pass and return values: either primitives, or references to objects.  The values may *read from* a variable by the call's parameter expression or *assigned to* a variable after the call's return.  But you are not *passing* the variable.  A variable and its value / contents are different things.

---

So the only way to implement a shared counter is to implement it as a shared counter **object**.

Note that "variable" and "object" mean different things, both in Java and in other programming languages.  You should NOT use the two terms interchangeable.  For example, when I declare this in Java:

```
 String s = "Hello";
```

the `s` variable is not a `String` object.  It is a variable that contains a *reference* to the `String` object.  Other variables may contain references to the same `String` object as well.  The distinction is even more stark when the objects are mutable.  (`String` is not mutable ... in Java.)

Here are the two (IMO) best ways to implement a shared counter object.

- You could create a custom Java `Counter` class with a `count` variable, a get method, and methods for incrementing, decrementing the counter.  The class needs to implement various methods as thread-safe and atomic; e.g. by using `synchronized` methods or blocks<sup>2</sup>.
- You could just use an `AtomicInteger` instance.  That takes care of atomicity and thread-safety ... to the extent that it is possible with this kind of API.

The latter approach is simpler and likely more efficient ... unless you need to do something special each time the counter changes.

(It is conceivable that you could implement a shared counter other ways, but that is too much detail for this answer.)

---

<sup>1 - I realize that I just said the same thing more than 3 times.  But as the Bellman says in ["The Hunting of the Snark"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43909/the-hunting-of-the-snark): *"What I tell you three times is true."*

2 - If the counter is not implemented using `synchronized` or an equivalent mutual exclusion mechanism with the appropriate *happens before* semantics, you are liable to see Heisenbugs; e.g. race conditions and memory visibility problems.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Two crucial things you're missing. Both individually explain this behaviour - you can 'fix' either one and you'll still see this, you'd have to fix both to see 1-20:

### Java is pass-by-value

When you pass `i`, you pass *a copy of it*. In fact, in java, **all** parameters to methods are **always** copies. Hence, when the thread does `t++`, it has absolutely no effect whatsoever on your `i`. You can trivially test this, and you don't need to mess with threads to see it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i = 0;
  add5(i);
  System.out.println(i); // prints 0!!
}

static void add5(int i) {
  i = i + 5;
}
```

Note that all non-primitives are references. That means: A copy of the reference is passed. It's like passing the address of a house and not the house itself. If I have an address book, and I hand you *a scanned copy* of a page that contains the address to my summer home, you can still drive over there and toss a brick through the window, and I'll 'see' that when I go follow my copy of the address. So, when you pass e.g. a `list` and the method you passed the list to runs `list.add("foo")`, you *DO* see that. You may think: AHA! That means java does *not* pass a copy, it passed the real list! Not so. Java passed a copy of a street address (A reference). The method I handed that copy to decided to drive over there and act - that you can see.

In other words, `=`, `++`, that sort of thing? That is done to the copy. `.` is java for 'drive to the address and enter the house'. Anything you 'do' with `.` is visible to the caller, `=` and `++` and such are not.

### Fixing the code to avoid the pass-by-value problem

Change your code to:

```
class thread_creation extends Thread {
    static int t; // now its global!
    
    public void run() {
      increment();
    }
    
    public void increment() {
        for(int i =0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
            t++;
//            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        thread_creation t1 = new thread_creation();
        thread_creation t2 = new thread_creation();
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println(thread_creation.t);
    }
}
```

Note that I remarked out the print line. I did that intentionally - see below. If you run the above code, you'd think you see 20, but depending on your hardware, the OS, the song playing on your mp3 playing app, which websites you have open, and the phase of the moon, it may be less than 20. So what's going on there? Enter the...

### The evil coin.

The relevant spec here is the JMM (The Java Memory Model). This spec explains precisely what a JVM must do, and therefore, what a JVM is free not to do, especially when it comes to how memory is actually managed.

The crucial aspect is the following:

- Any effects (updates to fields, such as that `t` field) **may or may not** be observable, JVM's choice. There's no guarantee that anything you do is visible to anything else... *unless* there exists a Happens-Before/Happens-After relationship: Any 2 statements with such a relationship have the property that the JVM guarantees that you cannot observe the lack of the update done by the HB line from the HA line.

HB/HA can be established in various ways:

- The 'natural' way: Anything that is 'before' something else _*and runs in the same thread* has an HB/HA relationship. In other words, if you do in one thread `x++; System.out.println(x);` then you can't observe that the `x++` hasn't happened yet. It's stated like this so that if you're not observing, you get no guarantees, which gives the JVM the freedom to optimize. For example, Given `x++;y++;` and that's all you do, the JVM is free to re-order that and increment y before x. Or not. There are no guarantees, a JVM can do whatever it wants.
- `synchronized`. The moment of 'exiting' a `synchronized (x) {}` block has HB to the HA of another thread 'entering' the top of any synchronized block on the same object, if it enters later.
- `volatile` - but note that with `volatile` it's basically impossible which one came first. But one of them did, and any interaction with a volatile field is HB relative to another thread accessing the same field later.
- thread starting. `thread.start()` is HB relative to the first line of the `run()` of that thread.
- thread yielding. `thread.yield()` is HA relative to the last line of the thread.

There are a few more exotic ways to establish HB/HA but that's pretty much it.

Crucially, **in your code there is no HB/HA between any of the statements that modify or print t!**

In other words, the JVM is free to run it all in such a way that the effects of various `t++` statements run by one thread aren't observed by another thread.

### What the.. WHY????

Because of efficiency. Your memory banks on your CPU are, relative to how fast CPUs are, **oceans** away from the CPU core. Fetching or writing to core memory from a CPU takes an incredibly long time - your CPU is twiddling its thumbs for a very long time while it waits for the memory controller to get the job done. It could be running hundreds of instructions in that time.

So, CPU cores **do not write to memory AT ALL**. Instead they work with caches: They have an on-core cache page, and the only interaction with your main memory banks (which are shared by CPU cores) is 'load in an entire cache page' and 'write an entire cache page'. That cache page is then effectively a 'local copy' that only that core can see and interact with (but can do so very very quickly, as that IS very close to the core, unlike the main memory banks), and then once the algorithm is done it can flush that page back to main memory.

The JVM needs to be free to use this. Had the JVM actually worked like you want (that anything any thread does is instantly observable by all others), then **anything** that **any** line does must first wait 500 cycles to load the relevant page, then wait another 500 cycles to write it back. All java apps would *literally* be 1000x slower than they could be.

This in passing also explains that actual synchronizing is **really slow**. Nothing java can do about that, it is a fundamental limitation of our modern multi-core CPUs.

### So, evil coin?

Note that the JVM does not guarantee that the CPU must neccessarily work with this cache stuff, nor does it make any promises about when cache pages are flushed. It merely limits the guarantees so that JVMs can be efficiently written on CPUs that work like that.

That means that any read or write to any field any java code ever does can best be thought of as follows:

The JVM first flips a coin. On heads, it uses a local cached copy. On tails, it copies over the value from some other thread's cached copy instead.

The coin is evil: It is not reliably a 50/50 arrangement. It is entirely plausible that throughout developing a feature and testing it, the coin lands tails every time it is flipped. It remains flipping tails 100% of the time for the first week that you deployed it. And then just when that big potential customer comes in and you're demoing your app, the coin, being an evil, evil coin, starts flipping heads a few times and breaking your app.

The correct conclusion is that the coin **will mess with you** and that you **cannot unit test against it**. The only way to win the game is to ensure that **the coin is never flipped**.

You do this by never touching a field from multiple threads unless it is constant (`final`, or simply never changes), or if *all* access to it (both reads and writes) has clearly established HB/HA between all threads.

This is hard to do. That's why the vast majority of apps don't do it at all. Instead, they:

- Talk between threads using a database, which has vastly more advanced synchronization primitives: Transactions.
- Talk using a message bus such as RabbitMQ or similar.
- Use stuff from the `java.util.concurrent` package such as a Latch, ForkJoin, ConcurrentMap, or AtomicInteger. These are easier to use (specifically: It is a lot harder to write code for these abstractions that is buggy but where the bug cannot be observed or tested for on the machine of the developer that wrote it, it'll only blow up much later in production. But not impossible, of course).

### Let's fix it!

volatile doesn't 'fix' ++. `x++;` is 'read x, increment by 1, write result to x' and volatile doesn't make that atomic, so we cannot use this. We can either replace `t++` with:

```
synchronized(thread_creation.class) {
  t++;
}
```

Which works fine but is really slow (and you shouldn't lock on publicly visible stuff if you can help it, so make a custom object to lock on, but you get the gist hopefully), or, better, dig into that j.u.c package for something that seems useful. And so there is! AtomicInteger!

```
class thread_creation extends Thread {
    static AtomicInteger t = new AtomicInteger();
    
    public void run() {
      increment();
    }
    
    public void increment() {
        for(int i =0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
            t.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        thread_creation t1 = new thread_creation();
        thread_creation t2 = new thread_creation();
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println(thread_creation.t.get());
    }
}
```

That code will print 20. Every time (unless those threads take longer than 500msec which technically could be, but is rather unlikely of course).

### Why did you remark out the print statement?

That HB/HA stuff can sneak up on you: When you call code you did not write, such as `System.out.println`, who knows what kind of HB/HA relationships are in that code? Javadoc isn't *that* kind of specific, they won't tell you. Turns out that on most OSes and JVM implementations, interaction with standard out, such as `System.out.println`, causes synchronization; either the JVM does it, or the OS does. Thus, introducing print statements 'to test stuff' doesn't work - that makes it impossible to observe the race conditions your code does have. Similarly, involving debuggers is a great way to make that coin really go evil on you and flip juuust so that you can't tell your code is buggy.

That is why I remarked it out, because with it in, I bet on almost all hardware you end up seeing 20 eventhough the JVM doesn't guarantee it and that first version **is broken**. Even if on your particular machine, on this day, with this phase of the moon, it seems to reliably print 20 every single time you run it.

Comment: There is no HB/HA relation. The relation is called happens-before.

Comment: The unit of memory a CPU deals with are called cachelines (or blocks).

Comment: To prevent a CPU from stalling on a write, the stores are placed in the store buffer.

Comment: Caches of different CPUs can share the same cache line. E.g. a non dirty cache line.

Comment: Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent. So it can't be that a CPU reads out of date data from the cache.

Comment: A database is not an alternative to memory synchronization. Apart from that, with databases, you can still run into various inconsistency problems even when a serializable isolation level is used.

Comment: You are talking about happens-before, but then mention race conditions. At the level of the JMM, the discussion is about data races. They are a different type of concurrency problem than a race-condition.

Comment: @pveentjer You seem to have issues with 'lowering yourself' to the viewpoint of someone quite new to programming. My explanation is likely to fly over their head - your details are an absolute certainty.

Comment: My primary issue is with confusing the TS with incorrect terminology and incorrect mental models.

Comment: @pveentjer - Well perhaps >>you<< should try to write an answer that explains to a beginner that which needs to be explained >>to them<< in terms that they will understand.  Hint: the instant that you mention "happens before" you will have lost them entirely. But don't let that stop you coming up with a better way to describe it to them.

Comment: But (hint 2) the real issue here is that the OP >thinks< they are using a shared variable, but in fact they aren't.  There are two distinct (non-shared) variables.  And the simplest / best solution is to use an `AtomicInteger` ... which renders all discussion of memory visibility semantics moot.

Comment: If you want to explain something to a beginner, at least use the appropriate terminology and mental models. If you can't do that, it is better to not mention it, otherwise, you are only adding to the confusion.